# Como pegar o texto de um select com formBuilder? - Angular 6

Tags: angular, formulário, html-select

Gostaria de pegar o valor do texto e não o 'value' do select.

```
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="ProductName">Product Name</label>
        <select id="ProductName" class="form-control" formControlName='ProductName' autofocus #focusHere (change)="retrieveID()">
          <option *ngFor="let productName of productNames" [value]="productName.id">{{ productName.ProductName }}</option>
        </select>
        <small *ngIf="productForm.get('ProductName').errors?.required" class="text-danger d-block mt-2">Product Name is
          required!
        </small>
      </div>
```

Segue a lógica.

```
   registerProduct() {
    this.products.push({
      ProductName: this.productForm.get('ProductName').value,
      ProductElement: this.productForm.get('ProductElement').value,
      ProductAttribute: this.productForm.get('ProductAttribute').value,
      ProductAttributeValue: this.productForm.get('ProductAttributeValue').value,
      Quantity: this.productForm.get('Quantity').value,
      FK_ID_QUOTE: this.quote.id
    })

    this.productForm.reset()
    this.focusHere.nativeElement.focus()
    return this.products
  }
```

Preciso pegar o valor do texto e o valor do value (id, nome).

Answer (score -1):

No ts:

```
objeto: any;
```

No html:

```
<select id="ProductName" class="form-control" formControlName='ProductName' autofocus #focusHere (change)="retrieveID()" [(ngModel)]="objeto">
```

Isso é bem básico cara. Dê uma olhada no curso de angular no youtube. Possui vários. Comece por ai, ou no [tour of heroes oficial do Angular](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart). Recomendo o Curso de Angular de Loiane Groner: [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPOMG0D57S0&list=PLGxZ4Rq3BOBoSRcKWEdQACbUCNWLczg2G) ou [aqui](http://loiane.training)